# Ensure Singleton pattern uses only one DB connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, singleton

Is there a way that i can check that my Singleton pattern is only using one connection to SQL Server 2008 R2 at a time?

I'm using the decoupled-data technique in that my methods request to connect to the server via a "Database Interface" class that employs the Singleton pattern to reduce the number of connections used.

Is there a connection ID or number I can get once the program connects to the server?  (So I can make sure that the number of active connections is in fact only 1 or 2)?

Comment: Just use locking, though I have no clue why you want to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to implement a bottle-neck in your system? It's almost always better to open and close/dispose (logical) connections immediately around the code that actually uses the connection, and let the connection pool take care of opening as many (physical) connections as are actually required.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to enforce such a situation. If you showed us some code, then perhaps we could answer more specifically. I would use a `using` clause.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//connection string)
{
    //do some database action inside the clause
}
```

This way, when you exit the using clause, the `SqlConnection` object would be disposed ensuring that only one will be used for each database access.

If you want to actually validate that only one connection is used at a specific point, then use a breakpoint on the .NET code and stop execution. Then open the [SQL Server profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) or the [SQL Server activity monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and check the connections. You could do this using three breakpoints (one before `using` clause, one inside `using` clause and the last breakpoint after the `using` clause) to verify the whole connection behaviour.

Hope I helped!